# jQuery loop on multiple input.files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to loop this on a multiple file input:

```
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#pprev_0')
        .attr('src', e.target.result);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
```

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
var fileCount = 0;
$("input[name='files[]']").each(function() {

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#pprev_'+fileCount)
        .attr('src', e.target.result)
        .css("display","block");
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[fileCount]);

    fileCount++;
});
```

alert() on fileCount output is a one time 0 on multiple file selection. no further alerts. If I take numbers instead of the fileCount var in code, it works at position. r.g. input.files[2] ...

Any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you do this: `$("input[name='files[]']").each(function() {` you are actually getting any  elements that match the selector. In this case, you get your single  multi file input (which is why you only see 1 alert. What you want to do is iterate over the files.

This page has code to do pretty much exactly what you want. I recommend you check it out:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

To apply it to your situation, you would do something like this:

```
var files = $('#files')[0].files; //where files would be the id of your multi file input
//or use document.getElementById('files').files;

for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#pprev_'+fileCount)
        .attr('src', e.target.result)
        .css("display","block");
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(f);

}
```

Comment: by adding this, it works fine! Thanks! var fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
 var files = fileInput.files;
 var file;

Comment: `for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++)` is difficult to read.  Is there a clearer way of looping?