# Validate three files input with js

Tags: jquery, validation, file-upload, input

I have three inputs in my form to upload file User can select n number of inputs to upload from 1 - 3 i want to made a check that not files is above the mentioned size file so i have used the following Script:

```
var fileInput = $('.registration_file');
var maxSize = fileInput.data('max-size');
$('#companyRegForm').submit(function(e){
    if(fileInput.get(0).files.length){
        var fileSize = fileInput.get(0).files[0].size; // in bytes
        if(fileSize>maxSize){
            alert('Dateigröße ist mehr dann ' + maxSize + ' bytes');
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

And mu Inputs are like:

```
<input accept=".jpeg,.pdf" data-max-size="500000" name="image_file_1" class="registration_file" type="file">
<input accept=".jpeg,.pdf" data-max-size="500000" name="image_file_2" class="registration_file registration_file_2" type="file">
<input accept=".jpeg,.pdf" data-max-size="500000" name="image_file_3" class="registration_file registration_file_3" type="file">
```

But in this case just first input is working other two are not validating and submit as it is without checking the file size,

That i need to do with this.

Comment: you have to loop all the three files

Comment: you mean .each(function)

Comment: Yes you can do that and you can get size and file type of each input file field

Comment: or you can use bootstrap validation plugin

Comment: Loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821402/jquery-loop-on-multiple-input-files - please seach google for your title next time

Comment: fileInput.get(0).files[0].size will always get the 1st file.
Use loop to get the size of all three files.